# Can not attach body to my POST request using Spring MockMvc

Tags: spring, rest, mockmvc

I'm trying to test my rest controller. No issues with GETs, but when I try to test a POST method I'm unable to attach the body.

```
private static final MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
                                                            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
                                                            Charset.forName("utf8"));
private ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    //...Create DTO
    //...Create same pojo but as entity

    when(serviceMock.addEntity(e)).thenReturn(e);

    mvc.perform(post("/uri")
        .contentType(contentType)
        .content(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(dto))
        )
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType)); //fails because there is no content returned
}
```

This is the request output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /uri
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
```

There is no body. Why? I have printed `jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)` and is not null.

edit:

Adding controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService service;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyMapper mapper;



    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<CompanyDTO> getCompanies() {
        List<Company> result = service.getCompanies();
        return mapper.toDtoL(result);
    }   

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public CompanyDTO createCompany(@RequestBody @Valid CompanyDTO input) {
        Company inputE = mapper.toEntity(input);
        Company result = service.addCompany(inputE);
        return mapper.toDto(result);
    }
```

Comment: That is the content of the response you are testing against

Comment: Please add the source of the controller.

Comment: @reos added controller code

Comment: the print() handler does not print the request body, but it do send the request body.

Comment: In your test, shouldn't this be post("/companies") instead of post("/uri") ?

Comment: @artemisian yes, that's a typo trying to "hide" my original code

Comment: @reos ok, then why the response body  is also null?

Comment: Please add the MockHttpServletResponse: , also verify if your controller is really returning something.

Comment: @LiLou_ as Reos suggested, debug your controller and check that mapper.toDto(result) is returning something

Comment: @artemisian the method works correctly. Prove: http://imgur.com/a/ef9aB Is the test that is failing.

Comment: @artemisian This is the line that is not doing what I expect: `when(serviceMock.addEntity(e)).thenReturn(e);` I debugged and on my controller, the returned value is null. Btw, I also confirm that the request has the body I'm telling to have. So why the mock is bad?

Comment: @Lilou_ shouldn't it be `when(serviceMock.addCompany(e)).thenReturn(e);` instead of `addEntity`?

Comment: @artemisian that is a typo

Comment: Can you post how you are creating the serviceMock bean?, also your config class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

1. The mock call should use `any` instead of a concrete object: `when(serviceMock.addCompany(any(Company.class))).thenReturn(e);`
2. I needed to override the equals method of the entity class to pass this statement: `verify(serviceMock, times(1)).addCompany(e);`